# Appending an ID to an uploaded file with Jquery Uploader

Tags: php, jquery, uploader

I am using the Jquery Uploader http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ to upload files to a website, it works fine, but the problem is it puts all the images in the same folder and I have no idea what is what. I have the following lines now setup (minus the POST $ID part) so that on each upload it saves the file name to the db, on the upload form is a field called equipmentID , what I am trying to do is to insert the data into the field that corresponds with the equipmentID , but im not sure how to get the form field data into the UploadHander.php as I don't know how or if jquery submits this data to the upload handler or if I need to tell it to.

Im not sure if something like this will work with jquery as Im not sure how it interacts with php files ?.

```
$ID = $_POST['equipmentID'];


function add_img($name, $ID)

{

$add_to_db = $this->query("INSERT INTO u5b0y_chronoforms_data_submitusedequipment WHERE equipmentID='$ID'     (photo) VALUES ('".$name."')") or die(mysql_error());

  return $add_to_db;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to know which file has been uploaded to the server you need either to add field in your ajax post request of your jquery uploader with the filename you want on your server side when it registers it or you can identify files by their user id and you can use $_session vars to recognise the file on the other side according that the script knows what picture type it should receive and put it into the right folders.

Comment: according to this, all fields get sent to the server automatically, but im not sure how to get them out at the other end https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data